# How can I remove a cron job set as user ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, cron

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have created a new cron job as a different user.
I started `gksu gnome-shedule` and set up a new cron and set it up as user `ubuntu`.

Now I can't edit or remove this job. Is there way to remove the job?

The job is listed when I run the following command:

```
sudo nano crontab -u ubuntu -l
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Or try sudo crontab -u ubuntu -e

Reasoning: From man crontab

> If  the -u option is given, it specifies the name of the user whose crontab is to be used (when listing) or modified (when editing). If this option is not given, crontab examines "your" crontab, i.e., the crontab of the person executing the command.  Note that su(8) can confuse crontab and that if you are running inside of su(8) you should always use the -u option for safety's sake.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and provide an explanation **why** this should work. To remove the negative reputation points, drop me a note so that I can review my assessment of your answer.  Alternatively, [delete] it altogether and the negative reputation points will be reversed automatically by the system. (I do this too for answers that give me negative reputation points) **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

To execute crontab as the user `ubuntu` do:

```
sudo -u ubuntu crontab -e
```

Or you can login as user `ubuntu` first with:

```
sudo su ubuntu -
```

and then:

```
crontab -e
```